# How to access value inside vector of vectors of type class

Tags: c++, vector

I'm in an introductory C++ class and we've been tasked to write a program that reads a .ppm picture file, copies it, then writes it to an output file.

To do this, my PpmPicture class has a vector of vectors, where each index contains a Pixel with red, green, and blue ints.

My problem is with my output function, where I'm trying to output those ints to a file. How do I go about accessing them individually? Here is my code, you can see where I'm trying to output those values at the bottom in my writePpmFile function. I know the picture.red[0][0] doesn't make any sense, I was just trying to brute force a solution and that happened to be the last thing I tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct Pixel {
    Pixel();
    Pixel(int redValue, int greenValue, int blueValue);
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
};

Pixel::Pixel() {
    red = 0;
    green = 0;
    blue = 0;
}

Pixel::Pixel(int redValue, int greenValue, int blueValue) {
    red = redValue;
    green = greenValue;
    blue = blueValue;
}

class PpmPicture {
public:
    PpmPicture();
    bool readPpmFile(string inputFile);
    int writePpmFile(string outputFile);
private:
    vector<vector<Pixel> > picture;
    int rows;
    int columns;
    int intensity;
};

PpmPicture::PpmPicture() {
    rows = 0;
    columns = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    PpmPicture myPic;

    if(argc != 3) {
        cout << "usage: inputfile outputfile";
        return 0;
    }

    myPic.readPpmFile(argv[1]);
    myPic.writePpmFile(argv[2]);
}

bool PpmPicture::readPpmFile(string inputFile) {
    Pixel pix;
    vector<Pixel> tempArray;
    fstream fin;
    string fileType;
    int i, j;

    fin.open(inputFile.c_str());
    //Check if file opened
    if(fin.fail()) {
        return false;
    }

    while(!fin.eof()) {
        //Input first four values into appropriate variables
        fin >> fileType >> columns >> rows >> intensity;
        //Fill tempArray with pixel values
        while(fin >> pix.red >> pix.green >> pix.blue) {
            tempArray.push_back(pix);
        }
    }

    //Read file until you reach the number of rows specified by the file
    for(j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        //Input pixel values into each index in the row array
        //Enter new row when one row's width is achieved
        for(i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            picture[j].push_back(tempArray[i]);
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int PpmPicture::writePpmFile(string outputFile) {
    ofstream fout;
    int i, j, temp;

    fout.open(outputFile.c_str());
    if(fout.fail()) {
        return -2;
    }

    if(columns < 0 || rows < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    fout << "P3" << endl;
    fout << columns << rows << endl;
    fout << intensity << endl;
    fout << picture.red[0][0];
    fout << picture.green[0][0];
    fout << picture.blue[0][0];

    /*for(j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        for(i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            fout << picture[j][i] << " ";
        }
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

I should add, like I said this is an introductory class so we haven't gone over a lot of shortcuts/different functions. So if possible keeping it somewhat simple (even if it isn't that efficient) would be preferred :)

Comment: Think inst as an instance of PpmPicture: 
inst.picture.at(i).at(k)

Comment: `picture[j][i]` gives you the `pixel` at position [i][j].  How would you get the r,g,b values of a regular pixel instance?

Comment: Of course it returns a Pixel instance, maybe you should implement a method for retrieving values of RGB as @NathanOliver suggested

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah! That makes so much sense. Is picture[j][i].red the correct syntax? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Toy_Reid You should try that.  You will be happy with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly a question of applying what you already know, but it seems like you're doing it in a sightly odd order.

Since `picture` is a `vector<vector<Pixel>>`, `picture[i]` is a `vector<Pixel>` and `picture[i][j]` is a `Pixel`.

The components of a `Pixel` are always accessed the same way – `pixelvalue.componentname` – so the components of this `Pixel` are `picture[i][j].red`, `picture[i][j].green`, and `picture[i][j].blue`.

Comment: You're right, I was definitely just having a lapse trying to figure out what order to do things in. The answer makes so much sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to this would be writing an [insertion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Stream_extraction_and_insertion) for `Pixel` for example:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& lhs, const Pixel& rhs) {
    lhs << rhs.red << ' ' << rhs.green << ' ' << rhs.blue;
}
```

Given this you can stream all of `vector<Pixel> picture` to `ostream fout` with only the command:

```
copy(cbegin(picture), cend(picture), ostream_iterator<Pixel>(fout, " "))
```

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't gone over copy, cend, or ostream_iterator yet. Getting there, though!

Comment: @Toy_Reid Yeah we never made it to `ostream_iterator`s in my C++ class, but keep them in the back of your head. Once you know what you're comfortable with iterators come back to them. You'll find them impossible to live without.